# Headerdoc generate without body tag

Tags: ios, objective-c, documentation, headerdoc

We are using headerdoc to create html files for our documentation which will be rendered as a partials in our web framework. We would like to know if there is a way to prevent head, html, and body tags from the html files that header doc generates since these docs will be rendered inside our web template.

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know there is no option to do that using `headerdoc`.

However you can create your own configuration file and use that configuration.
As mentioned in [HeaderDoc Usage](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/HeaderDoc/usage/usage.html):

```
headerdoc2html -c myCustomHeaderDocConfigFile.config MyHeader.h
```